# RubyプログラムからGETリクエストでPHPプログラム内のJavaScriptを実行したい

Tags: javascript, php, ruby

Rubyプログラムからphpプログラムが置かれたURLにGETリクエストをして、そのなかのJavaScriptを実行したい。
ブラウザから直接、パラメーターをつけてURLにアクセスするとJavaScriptが実行されるのですが、GETリクエストだと実行されない理由を教えてください。

Rubyプログラム

```
  uri = URI.parse("http://hoge.jp/hoge/hoge.php")
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(hoge: "fuga")
  Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

PHPプログラム

```
<?php
    $person = rawurldecode($_GET['hoge']);
    $person = mb_convert_encoding($fuga, "UTF-8");
?>
<script src="sample.js"></script>
<script>
    var person = <?php echo json_encode($person, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT); ?>;
//以下、JavaScriptの処理が続く
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScriptのコードを実行するのはブラウザだからです。ブラウザはGETリクエストを発行してその内容を受信し、受信したHTMLの中にJavaScriptのコードが含まれていれば(必要ならもう一度GETリクエストを発行してJavaScriptのコードを読み込んで)それを実行します。

それに対して、記載されているようなRubyのコードは「GETリクエストを発行してその内容を受信」するだけです。Ruby自体の中には受信したHTMLの中に含まれるJavaScriptのコードを実行するような機能はありませんので、あなたが書かれたようなコードでJavaScriptを実行することはできません。

Rubyからブラウザ(もしくはそれに相当するような「JavaScriptが実行できる何か」)を操作して「GETリクエストを発行してその内容を受信し、受信したHTMLの中にJavaScriptのコードが含まれていればそれを実行」させることが出来るかもしれませんが、記載されているようなRubyのコードとは全く違った形になるでしょう。

Comment: node.jsなどサーバーサイドJavaScriptを使えば、ブラウザではなくサーバーでJavaScriptを実行でき、今回の目的が達せられますか。

Comment: @sashihara さん、「今回の目的」が最終的にどんなものなのかがよくわからないのですが、node.jsは「JavaScriptが実行できる何か」の候補の一つではあると思います。